# Taking a contract role with a dated tech stack

Tags: software-industry

Just for some background : I am a senior level java developer and many of my jobs in the last decade have been as a contractor where I shift clients every 1 to 2 years. I place a high value on keeping up with current tech. My last couple of gigs have given me some limited cloud /AWS / devops experience writing mucroservice APIs with Spring Boot. This is of course the way everything is going so it is a good thing.

I was going to get out of consulting with my last gig which went well - they offered me an FTE but corona caused a hiring freeze and it got cancelled so now I am back with my consultant's cap on again looking for clients. It has been a bit longer than usual because of covid there are lots of contract gigs but lots of competition as well. Today I had a screen with a client that went well and it seems that if I do the followup call I would get offered a gig. ( Contracts move much faster than FTE interview processes !) However the hourly rate is lower than I usually get and the tech stack is dated, part of a stodgy old IT department of a corporation.

Now, it is tempting to take it so I have a bridge out of this covid crisis, the contract could last a year. However my worry is that I will erode my marketability taking such a gig. My experience is that generally clients look most closely at the last project you worked on, and being over a "certain age" and having that last role be a non cloud development role worries me. I also make it a policy to never quit a client before a contract ends, so the option of taking the role as a stopgap and then switching to a better client in a couple of months is not appealing ( and that doesn't look good on the CV either. People don't care if you contract, but a contract you work that is less than 6 months raises eyebrows. )

I am not currently facing a cash crisis since I have been contracting a while and have planned for these kind of downtimes. However the months are starting to stretch out. Given that we are the covid 19 uncertainty and downturn, should I take a survival mentality and take this gig, and focus on having an income for a year or do I pass and hope for a better contract to come along soon that has a current stack that increases my future employability?

Note that you can go from finding out about an opportunity for a contract from a recruiter to getting an offer from their client in as little as 5 days as opposed to FTE jobs which take weeks. On the other hand it could be months before I land a gig and then there is the job gap to consider. Any thoughts from anyone, particularly those with lots of contract and consulting experience?

Comment: My thought: paragraphs were invented because they make walls of text easier to read.

Comment: I do keep up with tech on my own. But contract roles want demonstrated skills on the job.

Comment: most contracting jobs would be on common tech stacks I would think. Cutting edge stuff is not something you'd entrust to a contractor, perhaps a consultant team, but not Joe Bloggs

Comment: It's not about cutting edge so much as there has been a huge paradigm shift to Devops/ Cloud / AWS/ docker etc which is fundamentally different than old school monolithic architectures. I already have a start on this with my last two gigs but need to expand more into kubernates, lamda etc. I fear taking a step backwards and then people only looking at the last gig I did and not being up to date in the cloud. I fear looking like an old dude who didn't keep up. That is lethal in the contract world

Answer (score 1):

I'm a front-end developer, so my experience may not be directly applicable, but I generally don't mind doing a contract on a project using more 'legacy' technology. (These days that would probably be something like JQuery, or AngularJS). My view is that if companies are still using it, then it's still relevant, and I would expect prospective employers in the future to be able to look at my abilities in the round rather than focus on particular technologies I happened to be working on in my last job. Obviously, I also keep abreast of latest developments in the field as well.

Comment: Yes, I have done angular / react projects on my own. But you can't get the same depth you would have  building a real front end application for a client. Saying you built a react front end for a massively scalable architecture at American Express carries a  lot more weight than doing a react tutorial at home

Answer (score 1):

> I am not currently facing a cash crisis since I have been contracting a while and have planned for these kind of downtimes.

Good, don't wait until you are.

In uncertain times you grab what stability you can, because it gives you a bit of padding against hard times and the ability to focus on the broader picture without worrying about the immediate issues.